# When scraping the TSP website, I can't access the data in the share price table using excel vba html scraping

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am scraping the website "https://www.tsp.gov/fund-performance/share-price-history/" and I can debug.print the innerHTML if I use getElementbyId("dynamic-share-price-div") but not if I use getElementbyId("dynamic-share-price-table") which is closer to the table I want. Why can I print the innerHTML for one but not the other when they both have unique div Id. I just can't figure out how to get to the only table in the div. I have tried using getElementsbyTagName("table")(0) on each of the Div objects returned but I get nothing. When I use the getElementbyID on the div id going directly to the table (2nd unique div id above), I can't even debug.print the innerHTML. Here is my code.

Sub TSPxmlGet()

```
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim reqURL As String
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

reqURL = "https://www.tsp.gov/fund-performance/share-price-history/"

req.Open "GET", reqURL, False

req.send

If req.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox req.Status & " - " & req.StatusText
    Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = req.responseText

Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("dynamic-share-price-div")

'Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("dynamic-share-price-table") 'This one shows that Div element has been populated

Debug.Print HTMLDiv.innerHTML 'Will get print in immediate window only for first choice (-div but not -table)

'Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

Set HTMLTable = HTMLDiv.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)  ' Says object required

Debug.Print HTMLTable.innerHTML  ' get nothing in immediate window since no object
```

End Sub

The Xpath of the table body is: "/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody" but I don't know how to code the Xpath

Comment: Do you want to scrape only prices ? It is very difficult to understand what do you want to do, if you do not post your code here.

Comment: Thank you for looking. I have added the code. I am trying to get to the prices table but I can't get an indication that I have located the table since I can't print the innerText of the table.

Comment: I meant to say can't debug.print innerHTML to show I have gotten to the table

Comment: My goal is to get the whole table with all the prices of the various funds into my spreadsheet

Comment: If you attack this url https://www.tsp.gov/data/getSharePricesRaw_startdate_20220424_enddate_20220524_Lfunds_1_InvFunds_1_download_0.html?startdate=2022-04-26&enddate=2022-05-26&Lfunds=1&InvFunds=1&download=0 with this user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36 it will give you all data. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Here you have working curl: curl --location --request GET 'https://www.tsp.gov/data/getSharePricesRaw_startdate_20220424_enddate_20220524_Lfunds_1_InvFunds_1_download_0.html?startdate=2022-04-26&enddate=2022-05-26&Lfunds=1&InvFunds=1&download=0' \
--header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36'

Comment: Thank you for your reply MeT. That link you provide appears to work with old website but now it doesn’t allow start and end dates. If I provide current dates, it doesn’t  return anything.